# Use variable in file path in R

Tags: r, bash, path

In bash I can do:

`BLA=some/directory` and then

```
MyFavoriteFile1=/some/path/to/$BLA/myfile1.someextension
MyFavoriteFile2=/some/path/to/$BLA/myfile2.someextension
```

I was wondering if the same does exist in R? So that I would only have to change `BLA` once in the whole script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `file.path`:

```
dir <- file.path("some", "path")
bla <- file.path("some", "directory")
files <- c("file1.R", "file2.exe")

file.path(dir, bla, files)
```

Produces:

```
[1] "some/path/some/directory/file1.R"   "some/path/some/directory/file2.exe"
```

You could also use `paste` to generically concatenate strings, but `file.path` makes sure the correct directory separators are used for your OS, etc.